# Do Emiya Shirou and Arturia ever meet again after Fate/stay night?

Tags: fate-stay-night

Do Emiya Shirou and Arturia ever meet again after Fate/stay night, 
spoiler next

> I'd like to know because it's pretty sad that she says that she loves him then dies.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you mean Kiritsugu, as in Saber's master during the fourth Grail War, and the guy who is Shirou's dad? Because I'm pretty darned sure Saber was not, in fact, in love with him.

Comment: remember that Kiritsugu's last name is Emiya so in japanese his name is Emiya Kiritsugu. he adopted Shirou so SHriou becomes Emiya Shirou

Comment: Changed name to Emiya Shirou (that's who i meant to put)

Comment: Realta Nua "last episode" (the epilogue after you've completed the whole game); Fate Hollow Ataraxia´s true ending (epilogue after you've completed 100% of the game) and UBW good ending (Saber wants to stay in this world because Shirou gives her love points unlike the true ending). My favourite one is Ataraxia's true ending (which was written by Nasu and takes place outside of the time loop) as Shirou gets to have Saber as his servant and they live happily. Rin was very nice when she resurrected her to give her to him (as mana is not needed this time as the game explains).

Comment: IMPORTANT:And regarding "last episode", it can also happen in other timelines/routes but it is sure to happen after Fate's true ending. The reason is that it is done as an epilogue for such ending (it actually says epilogue) and Nasu said in his blog it is Fate's route true ending. Nasu has made epilogues for all 3 true endings. In the original game he did Heaven's Feel true ending epilogue. After some time he did Fate's true ending epilogue "last episode" and recently he made UBW's true ending epilogue (an 11 page script that was handed to Ufotable in order to make the epilogue episode).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes they do.

In the Visual Novel of Fate Stay/Night Realta Nua, once you have seen all five endings, a new ending appears accessible from the title screen called -Last Episode-. This is in two parts: a monologue of the Fate Route and a second part where Arturia is hearing from Merlin about a miracle achievable by two people, one who "wait endlessly" and one who "pursue endlessly", and eventually the pursuer will stop when they reach the waiter.

What Merlin is referring to is Arturia waiting and Shirou pursuing. Eventually Shirou reaches [Avalon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUpgo.png) where Arturia is sleeping and the two finally reunite. It's not entirely certain how long it took Shirou to reach Avalon however, considering that Avalon transcends all magic including the 5 Magics it must have taken an eternity for Shirou to reach.

In Unlimited Blade Works, because Caster canceled the contract between Saber and Shirou, Rin is able to from a contract with Saber. In the Good Ending of Unlimited Blade Works, we see that Rin is able to maintain Saber's Prana Supply but complains she finds it hard supplying her with energy without something like the Holy Grail. You can see this has Shirou being able to stay with Saber. However in Unlimited Blade Works, Rin is Shirou's love interest so with the True Ending for Unlimited Blade Works where Saber does disappear at the destruction of the Grail, it can be assumed that Shirou loves Rin more and does not go to find Saber so -Last Episode- won't occur.

In Fate/Hollow Ataraxia, Arturia comes back thanks to Rin's and Ilya's experiment to make the Jewel Sword into a pendant to allow easier use of the 2nd Magic. This allows Fuyuki City to becomes a place where "any and all events are possible", so all the Servants are brought back including Saber. In Avanger's design to recreate the 3rd Holy Grail War, because in the 3rd war the Edelfelt Sisters used their Sorcery Trait to summon 2 Sabers, this is mimicked in this new war with Arturia having a second personality in the form of Saber-Alter which is her dark corrupted self from the Heaven's Feel Route of the visual Novel.

I should point out that Fate/Hollow Ataraxia occurs in a parallel timeline where at least the Fate and Heaven's Feel routes occurred at the same time as Sakura is shown wearing a sleeve reminiscent from when she had a contract with Avanger, Alter-Saber cannot exist unless she was corrupted in the Grail (Heaven's Feel), Ilya is alive and well (Fate), the Vessel of the Holy Grail was destroyed (Fate), and the Greater Grail is thought to still be operational just without any purpose for all the prana it has collected from two wars, so -Last Episode- may still occur after Fate/Hollow Ataraxia.

Comment: Comment (you don't have to answer, it's just a comment): I personally prefer Ataraxia's true ending/epilogue (which was written by Nasu and happens outside of the time loop) to "Last episode". Shirou getting an end where he has Saber as his servant in this world is a good way for Nasu to end this part of the franchise (before moving to other universes with new main characters).

Answer (score 4):

Going off the assumption that you are actually asking about Emiya **Shirou** (i.e. the guy who is the protagonist of Fate/stay night) - see below for spoilers concerning the visual novel (and hence also the UBW movie).

> The answer is **yes, sort of**. The first thing you need to know is that Archer (the red man, not Gilgamesh) is actually Shirou. I don't think you are told this in the TV series, but you do learn this if you watch the UBW movie.
>
>  Now, in the visual novel there are three routes, with a total of five non-bad endings between them. Once you have achieved each of the five endings (that is, Fate, UBW Good, UBW True, HF Normal, and HF True), you gain access to a bonus ending called **Last Episode** (this might only occur in Realta Nua; I'm not sure).
>
>  What basically happens there is that you get a short recap/sampling of the events of the Fate route, mostly focused on things Saber did, plus a few flashbacks to her childhood, when she first pulled the sword from the stone. Eventually, you get to the scene where Saber tells Shirou she loves him, and then disappears.
>
>  And then after that, we get some internal monologue from Shirou-turned-Archer, bemoaning the worthlessness of his existence, followe by some internal monologue from Saber, longing for Shirou. Merlin (I think) pops in and monologues at Saber for a while.
>
>  Finally, after an undetermined length of time, Shirou/Archer and [Saber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHFRq.png) meet again in some sort of afterlife-y place that most people agree is Avalon. Hooray!
>
>  So why is the answer to your question "sort of"? This is because the Type-Moon universe has this notion of parallel worlds in which basically everything that is shown to happen actually happens in one parallel world or another. So, Last Episode presumably happens at least in some variants of the Fate timeline, but doesn't happen in all timelines.

---

If, for some reason, you actually want to know if Kiritsugu and Saber ever meet again, the answer is no. Kiritsugu dies a few years after the fourth war, and that's the end of that.

Comment: Most would assume Emiya since Kiritsugu and her did not see eye to eye at all.

Answer (score 2):

Memor's answer is very good. I'm gonna work on it and explain why I think there is a fourth ending in which we have Saber X Shirou.

Let's begin with the basics. There is a common belief that states Shirou gets Rin as a love partner more times than any other girl. I'm gonna explain why I believe Saber is the girl Shirou gets more times, not Rin.

1. As Memor stated the ending of the very first route of Fate Stay Night (Fate route) is "the Last Episode", where Shirou and Saber live happily ever after in Avalon, a magical paradise where it will be just the 2 of them as a couple.
2. In UBW if you give points to Saber she will feel cherished by Shirou and will decide to stay with him in the real world (in the visual novel she even says her only reason to stay is to watch over him. Later Rin gets angry and tells her not to flirt). In this ending Shirou gets both Rin and Saber, who will train Shirou in magic and Martial arts and guide him to his happiness as Rin promised.
3. Fate Hollow Atarxia's true ending: Shirou has the ultimate harem. He has Saber, Rin, Sakura, Caren, Ayako, Bazett... and all of them fight between themselves for his love.
4. Nasu said:

"Nasu said:

"I personally wrote “Reunion”, the introductory portion of Fate/hollow ataraxia with the intention of it being the ending of a certain route in Fate/stay night and the ending of “hollow ataraxia”"

This Reunion was confirmed as the scene "Reopening"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ShPOZvbFLA

So basically we have another ending that was meant to happen in the original game. After that it was meant to happen at the end of its sequel Ataraxia.

Whatever the situation just keep in mind that Nasu wrote that scene as an ending and can therefore be considered as such. It's no mere headcanon.
The way it is done it seems to be similar to UBW good ending, so I guess it could also be its future once Rin goes to Clock Tower considering that Saber says: ""with Rin gone, it is my duty to supervise you". But maybe it's better to just consider it another ending in which Rin leaves to study magic and Shirou and Saber live happily in this world. Basically they choose different paths as Shirou and Saber don't follow her (as Shirou does in UBW true ending)
The Saber eclipse scene shows in Fate Hollow a Saber that comes from UWB and that loves Shirou and has sex with him, so Saber X Shirou in UBW is there in my opinion.

So, what does it mean? It means Shirou gets saber in every possible way: A happily ever after in paradise, a harem with Rin, a harem with everyone and a happily ever after in this world just the 2 of them.

Comment: some corrections. 1) there are already 5 endings so the 4th ending is either the unobtained UBW ending or a Heaven's Feel Endind. 2) Shirou kills Saber in Heaven's Feel. unless this is different in the [Planned yet unimplemented Ilya route](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Illyasviel_von_Einzbern#Creation_and_Conception) then Shirou can't get Saber in every possible way.

Comment: I know haha. It can't be Heaven's Feel cause he kills her as you say. It can't be Illya's route either IMO as it doesn't exist and I doubt Nasu would write the ending first (Not to mention that he said "the ending of a certain route in fate stay night": and Illya's route doesn't exist in fate stay night as of today). My guess is that it would be the UBW route as you suggest. Maybe I wasn't clear enough when I said in every possible way. I didn't mean in every route (as he just gets Sakura and Rider in Heaven's Feel) I mean in every form (harems and the 2 of them in avalon and in this world)

Comment: That's great! I didn't know Nasu had gone out of his way to say he had written a Saber-Shirou ending in planet earth for the original visual novel. The fact that it was included in F/H/A makes it canon to me, it is no longer in Nasu's mind, it was included in the VN. It is very funny you said it might be UBW future consdering in the anime she says "I am allowed to bring 1 apprentice", and 1 isn't  2. I don't think it is HF as there is no need of her being there.After all Shirou has 0% chance of becoming archer there since he gave up on being a hero. He has Rider as mistress, no need for other

Comment: Comment (you don't have to answer): We already have an ending where Shitou and Saber get to live in this world even without that: it's Ataraxia's true ending/epilogue (which was written by Nasu and happens outside of the time loop), where Saber gets to stay in this world as Shirou's master. Rin was very nice when she resurrected her to give her to him (as mana is not needed this time as the game explains).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to mainly focus on the Last Episode, stating a few things that weren't said in other answers.

Main point: The answer is YES as you're referring to the Fate route's true ending (as it is its canon epilogue). But the Fate route has many endings, and so do other routes/timelines. In this case, regarding the rest of the timelines, the answer is Maybe, sort of. Because of how Nasu made it, it can also happen in the rest of the timelines.

Before continuing, the 100% canon endings written by Nasu where Shirou and Arturia live together happily are:

- Last episode
- Unlimited Blade Works good ending: In the VN, if Shirou appoints love points to Saber, the good ending will happen and Saber will say she stays for him.
- Ataraxia's true ending outside of the loop once 100% of the game is completed: Shirou gets Saber as his servant and they live happily.

"Last episode" can also happen in different timelines/routes but it is sure to happen after Fate's true ending. The reason is that it is done as an epilogue for such ending (it actually says epilogue).

Nasu has made epilogues for all 3 true endings. In the original game, he did Heaven's Feel true ending epilogue. After some time he did Fate's true ending epilogue "last episode" and recently he's made UBW's true ending epilogue (an 11-page script that was handed to Ufotable in order to make the epilogue episode).

---

It isn't questioned but I'm gonna address a few doubts the OP may have.
You may think that even though it's the canon epilogue written by Nasu, it is also fanservice because of how happy it is.

Actually, the reality is that all happy endings if you reach the end of the game are strongly criticised by the VN community as fanservice.

The last episode makes a lot of sense as Fate's true ending epilogue (as Nasu has created it) because:

1. Nasu has stated that in every route, the chances of Shirou becoming Archer are so close to zero they are not worth mentioning. When asked if Archer comes from the Fate route in interviews, he has denied it. Archer comes from a timeline where Rin didn’t summon him.

   If he doesn’t become Archer in any final ending from each route, it is because the heroine saves her. It makes perfect sense for Shirou to look for Saber and for Saber, who loves him deeply, to suffer waiting for him (risking suffering for all eternity). After that, they reach their happily ever after. Otherwise, Shirou would become Archer, which is something Nasu has told us doesn’t happen.
2. Saber loves Shirou a lot. After the H-scene in the Fate route, Saber’s mind is 100% set on Shirou. She was also very proud saying things like “Shirou knows my body best” and stuff like that. It was clear she loved him, but after that, she’s so lovestruck she can’t even spar with him. Her attitude towards the rest of the people remains the same though. She also sacrifices her Holy Grail dream for him.

   In UBW, Rin says Saber is way too dedicated to Shirou. Before the final fight, Saber tells Shirou “Shirou, you are still my master”, and before dying in the true ending, she says it’s normal because “Shirou already has Rin”. In UBW's good ending, Saber flirts with Shirou as Rin states and she says she stays just for him.

   The only difference between the good and true endings is that in the good ending, Shirou gives love points to Saber, so she wishes to stay. So we have a Saber class servant that willingly states “Shirou, you are still my master” while having another master, and in the visual novel after Rin saves her, she flirts with her master’s boyfriend. As I said, the only difference between UBW's true and good endings is that in the Good ending, Shirou gives points to Saber. That’s the reason she wishes to stay, she feels Shirou really cares for him in the good ending because of the increased affection that Shirou has for her.

   After knowing this, it makes perfect sense for Arturia to wait for Shirou (risking suffering for all eternity as Merlin says).
3. The rest of the endings are just as fanservice as this one.

   - Heaven’s Feel true ending: This is the first epilogue Nasu wrote. You can find people everywhere saying it is a nonsensical happy ending. The rational ending after everything that happened should be the normal ending. Sakura should be a deranged girl, not a mentally healthy happy girl.
   - Fate’s true ending “last episode”: Because of their deep love, both Saber and Shirou forge their own happy ending in Avalon. It is the same as Heaven’s Feel true ending where Sakura and Shirou work really hard to get that ending.
   - UBW true ending epilogue: Nasu wrote the epilogue for UBW true ending recently and people complain it’s too happy (even though it’s based on a manuscript written by him which is actually much happier that the episode itself).
   - UBW good ending: This is the most attacked by far. People say that the fanservice reached new heights and that it’s impossible to happen. I’ve read HUNDREDS of comments saying UBW's good ending is just mere wish-fulfillment and that Saber shouldn’t be able to be maintained in this world no matter how much Shirou bangs both girls to help.
   - Ataraxia’s ending outside of the time loop once 100% of the game has been completed: This ending is just too perfect if you happen to be Shirou.

At the end of the day, FSN is mostly good and does more thing right than wrong, but it’s still deeply, deeply flawed, and the endings, in particular, is not its strong side.